# Stop OpenLayers 3 map firing click event after dragging

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers 3 map with a source of `ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'osm' })`. I haven't added a DragPan interaction, but the map is draggable anyway - which I want it to be.

I also have a click event for the map:

```
$(MapUtility.map.getViewport()).on('click', function(e) {
    //Stuff
});
```

which fires every time I finish dragging the map.

I used to have a similar problem with a DragBox interaction and solved it by calling `e.preventDefault()` at the start of my boxend event. However, that was an interaction I added and wrote the event for. The DragPan is in ol.js and I'd rather not change that if possible.

Is there something I can do in my click event to check whether the click was caused by DragPan? Alternatively, is there a way to amend the behaviour of this instance of the DragPan interaction without changing it globally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, with a click event firing when dragging a map, when using:

```
map.getViewport().addEventListener('click', function);
```

I have changed this to use the ol3 event 'singleclick', the singleclick has a small delay to ensure it is not triggered by a drag or doubleclick:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  var pixel = evt.pixel;
}
```

This way also provides more useful parameters on the event.

Source: [ol3-dev discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ol3-dev/GjPClfy9wHc/MaqHkwJUn3sJ)